# Wie spricht man im Deutschen "Excel" aus?

Tags: pronunciation

Ein beliebtes Computerprogramm zum Rechnen in Tabellen ist unter dem Namen "Excel" bekannt. Der Name referiert, wie man vermuten kann, sowohl auf "exzellent" wie auch auf Tabellenkästchen (Englisch: cells).

Jüngst ist mir aufgefallen, dass es zwei Aussprachevarianten dazu gibt. In meiner Alltagsumgebung spricht man das Wort meisten aus wie

> Äxl

also sehr eingedeutscht. (Allerdings bin vermutlich ich derjenige, der in meiner Umgebung das Wort am häufigsten verwendet. Vielleicht höre ich vor allem mich selbst.)

Daneben gibt es aber noch die Aussprachevariante

> Ekséll

mit Betonung auf der zweiten Silbe. Diese Variante scheint mir im Ursprungskulturkreis dieses Produktnamens gängig zu sein.

Was ist verbreitete und/oder gute Praxis im Deutschen? Wie sollte man das Wort aussprechen?

Gibt man sich durch Verwendung unterschiedlicher Ausspracheformen als einer bestimmten Personengruppe zugehörig oder aus einer bestimmten Region kommend zu erkennen?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73030/discussion-on-question-by-christian-geiselmann-wie-spricht-man-im-deutschen-exc).

Answer (score 12):

Man sollte jedes Wort so aussprechen, dass es die anderen verstehen. Mit anderen Worten: Man sollte sich der Mehrheit anschließen. Dass das Wort aus dem Englischen kommt, macht dabei nichts, man darf es trotzdem deutsch aussprechen.

Ein vergleichbares Beispiel ist das Wort *»Jute«* (eine grobe Faser, aus der man z.B. Säcke macht). Das ist dem Ursprung nach ein englisches Wort und wird in Amerika und England als [ʤuːt] (also ungefähr so wie *»dschuut«*) ausgesprochen, aber wenn du das Wort in einer deutschsprachigen Konversation so aussprichst, wirst du viele fragende Gesichter sehen, weil man dich nicht versteht. Gängig im deutschen Sprachraum ist die Aussprache [ˈjuːtə] (also so wie *»juute«*), was ganz den deutschen Regeln für die Zuordnung von Lauten zu Buchstaben entspricht.

Im Fall von *»Excel«* ist das deswegen nicht ganz so einfach, weil es für den Konsonantencluster *»XC«* kein deutschsprachiges Vorbild gibt.

Die allgemeinen Regeln sagen nämlich, dass bei einem Nomen, das zwei Silben hat, wovon die zweite als (geschriebenen) Vokal den Buchstaben *e* enthält, diese zweite Silbe eine Reduktionssilbe sein muss. Allerdings ist die Silbenteilung dann Exc-el, was genau das bereits erwähnte Problem mit dem Konsonantencluster aufwirft.

Nur in Ausnahmefällen ist bei zweisilbigen Wörtern die zweite Silbe betont. Im Fall von *Excel* hat das aber den Vorteil, dass dann das C in die zweite Silbe rutscht, also Ex-cel, wodurch es keinen Konsonantencluster mehr gibt.

---

Im Detail:

Falls es sich bei der letzten Silbe um eine Reduktionssilbe handelt, wird im Fall der Endung *-el* das E gar nicht ausgesprochen, die Funktion des Silbenkerns übernimmt dann das L, das als vokalisiertes L ausgesprochen wird. (Beispiele: Engel = [ˈɛŋl̩]; Adel = [ˈaːdl̩]; Ekel = [ˈeːkl̩] usw.)

Die erste Silbe besteht dann aus *»Exc*«. Der Buchstabe *»x«* wird üblicherweise als *»ks«* ausgesprochen und »*c*« als *»ts«*. Das ergäbe die Silbe *»eksts«* (in Lautschrift: [ˈɛksʦ]). Das ist für deutschsprachige Zungen kaum in einer Silbe auszusprechen (vor allem, weil diese Folge die [Sonoritätsregeln](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonorit%C3%A4tshierarchie) verletzt). Daher hat sich eingebürgert, das *»t«* wegzulassen, wodurch die beiden *»s«* zu einem gesprochenen Konsonanten verschmelzen, und sich für die erste Silbe *Eks* ergibt.

In IPA-Lautschrift schaut das ganze Wort dann so aus:

> Excel = [ˈɛksl̩].

Betont man hingegen die zweite Silbe, so wird das *»c«* als Teil der zweiten Silbe aufgefasst. Die erste Silbe besteht dann nur aus *»Ex«*«, was leicht auszusprechen ist (nämlich wie *eks*: [ɛks]), und die zweite Silbe ist dann *»cel«* was als *»tsel«* ausgesprochen wird: [ʦɛl]

Das ganze Wort in dieser Variante:

> Excel = [ɛksˈʦɛl]

Beide Varianten sind in Verwendung, aber die Version mit einer Reduktionssilbe am Ende (also [ˈɛksl̩]) ist weitaus häufiger.

Comment: Parbleu! Eine so tiefgründige Antwort hatte ich wirklich nicht erwartet. Vielen Dank. Das sind sehr interessante Erläuterungen. - Kleine Anmerkung vielleicht: Die Aussprache als [ɛksˈʦɛl], die du zuletzt erörterst, scheint mir eher hypothetisch (von den durch den Usus etablierten Regeln des Deutschen abgeleitet); in der Praxis habe ich sie noch nicht gehört, sondern wenn dann eben etwas englischartiges wie *ekséll*.

Answer (score 5):

Hubert Schölnasts Antwort ist relativ präzise auf die exakte Formulierung zugeschnitten.

Versteht man die Frage aber nicht als "wie wird Excel im Deutschen ausgesprochen" sondern als "wie wird Excel von Deutschmuttersprachlern oder Menschen in überwiegend deutscher Sprachumgebung ausgesprochen", dann bedarf es einer Ergänzung, denn Schreibweise und Aussprache sind für deutsche Ohren und Zungen zunächst immer ein Rätsel.

Die originalsprachliche Aussprache findet sich beispielsweise in diesem Werbeclip der Herstellerfirma: [Introduction to Microsoft Excel 1992 (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/kOO31qFmi9A?t=61)

Daraus kann entnommen werden, dass **[ɪkˈsel]** die englische Originalvariante ist. Diese wird von "Kennern", "Kosmopoliten", "Eingeweihten" bevorzugt. Also höheres Bildungsniveau oder auch hinunter bis zum oberen Management, "Profis"; und natürlich solche, die mal irgendwann nachgesehen oder nachgefragt haben, wie man es denn "richtig ausspricht", bzw. es einfach zuerst so von einem Vorbild gehört haben. Letzteres Argument gilt natürlich für alle Varianten hier.

Heimanwenderinnen und Sekretäre, Gelegenheitsnutzer und mittleres Management sagen offenbar auf deutsch eher die von Ihnen als "richtig" *vermutete* und tatsächlich aber halb eingedeutschte Variante, meist (a) **[ˈɛksl̩]** oder etwas näher am Original aber mit der häufig zunächst unvermuteten Betonung (b) **[ɛkˈsɛl]**. Diese beiden Varianten dürften insgesamt am häufigsten zu hören sein. Dabei ist aus heute fast schon historischer Sicht zu bemerken, dass früher a wesentlich dominanter verteilt war als b, b in letzter Zeit aber stark zugenommen hat.

Eine vollständig an deutsche Aussprachegewohnheiten angepasste Variante ist dann die tz-Laut enthaltende Variante **[ɛksˈʦɛl]**. Neben besonders germanisch orientierten Anglizismenverächtern wohl am häufigsten bei jeglicher Form von "Anfänger" zu hören.

Die genannten Begriffe zur Gruppenbeschreibung sind bitte nicht als Wertung zu lesen, lediglich als anschauliche Beschreibung. Größere Überlappungen in den Gruppen sind ohnehin zu erwarten. Ferner sind einige Betriebskulturen zu beobachten. Deren Eigenheiten hier gar nicht richtig erfasst werden können. Angestellte der Firma [IBM Deutschland](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM) beispielsweise achten peinlich stolz darauf, immer die vollständig eingedeutschte Variante "die Ih Be Em" zu verwenden.

Entscheidend scheint mir, dass die meisten, die die Betonung auf der zweiten Silbe kennen und gewöhnlich benutzen, die Betonung auf der ersten Silbe als falsch empfinden und die Nutzer entsprechend für uniformiert halte (Ah, so einer!). Umgekehrt reagieren Erstsilbenbetoner auf den Hörkontakt mit der Betonung auf der zweiten Silbe oft mit Skepsis oder Unverständnis (Wie bitte? / Komisch. Was soll das?).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72991/discussion-on-answer-by-langlangc-wie-spricht-man-im-deutschen-excel-aus).